# Theorem about closed prenex wf.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson , page 94 , exercise 2.58(a).The problem goes something like this ,

> Show that a closed prenex wf $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ with $m \geq 0$ and $n \geq 1$ , is logically valid if and only if it is true for every interpretation with a domain of n objects.

Here , $\mathscr B$ is any wf that contains no quantifiers , function letters , or individual constants.

**My attempt**:

($\rightarrow$)

If $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is logically valid , then it true for every interpretation. Then , it is true for every interpretation with a domain of $n$ objects.

($\leftarrow$)

Here , $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is true for every interpretation with an domain of $n$ objects.I have to prove that $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is logically valid.Here are the following things I tried so far:

(1) Induction on $m$. 
(2) Induction on $n$. 
(3) A two layer induction on both $m$ and $n$. 
(4) Using theorem (VIII) in page 61. 
(5) Showing that $\mathscr B$ is an instance of a tautology 
(6) "Maybe" I could show that the predicate letters in $\mathscr B$ are in the
form $A^n(x_1,...,x_p,y_1,...,y_q)$ where $p \leq n$ and $q \leq m$. And  then  It could help me prove the main theorem (idk). 
(7) Shufflling the quantifiers $(\forall x)$ and $(\exists y)$ somehow. 
(8) First trying to prove that $\vdash \mathscr D$ (where $\mathscr D$ is $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ ) and then prove that $\mathscr D$ is logically valid (using Gödel's completeness theorem). 
(9) [Hint from @spaceisdarkgreen] Trying to prove the contrapositive of the original statement. 
(10) Using exercise 2.55 (a) [If a wf is not $k$-valid , then it is not $(k+1)$ valid]

But so far I did not get anywhere. Can someone give me a hint about this? Also is my proof for the ($\to$) case correct?

Comment: It is probably easiest to approach from the contrapositive: show that if the sentence is not valid (i.e. there's some interpretation where it's not true), then you can construct an interpretation on a domain with $n$ objects where it is not true.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I now tried to prove the contra-positive , but it still seems complicated and I am still stuck. Anyway , Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'd suggest trying this straightforwardly: if you have an interpretation with more than n objects, and want to check for a specific $x_1\ldots x_n$ in that interpretation that $\exists y_1 \ldots \exists y_n B$. 

How can you use the hypothesis to find such $y_1 \ldots y_n$ in the interpretation with more than $n$ objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll elaborate on my comment: Suppose you have an interpretation with more than $n$ objects, and want to check for a specific $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ that $\exists y_1\cdots\exists y_n B$. Restrict the interpretation to just $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. By the hypothesis, there are $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ in this restriction that (with the $x$s) satisfy $B$. Because of the restrictions on $B$, $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n$ satisfy $B$ in the original interpretation as well.

Comment: I am having some difficulty understanding your answer. Are you trying to prove that if the wf $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is k-valid , then it is logically valid?

Comment: I'm proving that if it is $n$-valid, then it is logically valid. This is specifically the $\Leftarrow$ direction of the problem. Note that this $n$ has to be the same as the number of universal quantifiers at the beginning, so you can restrict to the substructure which only contains $x_1,\ldots , x_n$.

Comment: But I cant seem to relate your proof with the original problem. Like , I cant seem to understand that what are the premisses and conclusion of your proof.

Comment: wait, I seem to understand what you are trying to prove. Can you show me a proof of the line "Because of the restriction on $B$ , $x_1 , ... , x_n , y_1 , ... , y_n$ satisfy $B$ in the original interpretation as well."

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is old and the questioner has, most likely, completed the problem, forgot or abandoned, I think it is appropriate to post a full solution of mine for anyone searching for it or just to check theirs. I am not a trained mathematician, so take it with a grain of salt. If it has blatant mistakes, I strongly encourage you to comment on it, so no one would be deluded.

Denote the prenex with $\mathscr C$ and assume it is true for any interpretation with $n$ elements in its domain.

If $M$ has fewer than $n$ elements in $D$, let $s$ be a sequence in it. If it does not satisfy $\mathscr C$, it would not satisfy it for some model of $n$ objects having $D$ as a subset of its domain and interpreting atomics as in $M$ for this subset. So $s$ must satisfy $\mathscr C$.

Now suppose $M$ has more than $n$ elements and some $s$ does not satisfy $\mathscr C$. Then it satisfies $(\exists x_1)\dots(\exists x_n)(\forall y_1)\dots(\forall y_m)\neg\mathscr B$. Let $s'$ be different from $s$ in at most $s(x_1), \dots, s(x_n)$ places that satisfies $(\forall y_1)\dots(\forall y_m)\neg\mathscr B$. Now, if we make an interpretation with a domain consisting solely of these $s'(x_1), \dots, s'(x_n)$ (adding any others to make $n$, if some are not distinct; it is possible, since the others do not change the following inference) that interprets atomics in $\mathscr C$ similarly, we would have a contradiction, since it has $n$ elements and $\mathscr C$ must be true in it (because $s'$ with out-of-domain elements replaced with any of available would satisfy $(\forall y_1)\dots(\forall y_m)\neg\mathscr B$ and $(\exists y_1)\dots(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$, here is a contradiction).