# Rigorous and complete proof of a theorem of closed prenex.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson , page 94 , exercise 2.58(a).The problem goes something like this ,

> Show that a closed prenex wf $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ with $m \geq 0$ and $n \geq 1$ , is logically valid if and only if it is true for every interpretation with a domain of n objects.

Here , $\mathscr B$ is any wf that contains no quantifiers , function letters , or individual constants.

I have asked this question once here [my previous attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137409/theorem-about-closed-prenex-wf) for a hint. I got a hint and accepted it. But it seems like I am still unable to construct a rigorous proof with it (maybe because I am very unexperienced with logic). So , I am now asking for a rigorous and complete proof with addition of some more attempts I made to solve this problem.

**My attempt**:

($\rightarrow$)

If $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is logically valid , then it true for every interpretation. Then , it is true for every interpretation with a domain of $n$ objects.

($\leftarrow$)

Here , $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is true for every interpretation with an domain of $n$ objects.I have to prove that $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is logically valid.Here are the following things I tried so far:

(1) Induction on $m$. 
(2) Induction on $n$. 
(3) A two layer induction on both $m$ and $n$. 
(4) Using theorem (VIII) in page 61. 
(5) Showing that $\mathscr B$ is an instance of a tautology 
(6) "Maybe" I could show that the predicate letters in $\mathscr B$ are in the
form $A^n(x_1,...,x_p,y_1,...,y_q)$ where $p \leq n$ and $q \leq m$. And  then  It could help me prove the main theorem (idk). 
(7) Shufflling the quantifiers $(\forall x)$ and $(\exists y)$ somehow. 
(8) First trying to prove that $\vdash \mathscr D$ (where $\mathscr D$ is $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ ) and then prove that $\mathscr D$ is logically valid (using Gödel's completeness theorem). 
(9) [Hint from @spaceisdarkgreen] Trying to prove the contrapositive of the original statement. 
(10) Using exercise 2.55 (a) [If a wf is not $k$-valid , then it is not $(k+1)$ valid] 
(11) This is one last attempt I made before giving up

1. Lets assume that $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is not logically valid.We have to prove that it is not $n$-valid. Because $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is not logically valid , there is an sequence in an interpretation $M$ that does not satisfy the above wf. Let $s$ be that sequence.
2. $s$ does not satisfy $(\forall x_1)...(\forall x_n)(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$
3. There exists a sequence $s'$ which differs from $s$ atmost the $i_1$th ,  ... , $i_n$th places that does not satisfy $\mathscr B$.
4. there is a sequence $s'$ having the elements $b_{i_1},...,b_{i_n}$ in the $i_1$th , ... , $i_n$th places that does not satisfy $(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$
5. No sequence $s''$ that difference from $s'$ atmost the $j_1$th , ... , $j_m$th places satisfy $\mathscr B$ .
6. There is a sequence $s''$ that has the elements $b_{i_1},...,b_{i_n},b_{j_1},...,b_{j_n}$ at the $i_1$th ,  ... , $i_n$th, $j_1$th , ... , $j_m$th places that does not satisfy $\mathscr B$
7. $\forall b = \{b_{i_1},...,b_{i_n}\}$ and $\exists b = \{b_{i_1},...,b_{i_n}\}$
8. $\exists b \subseteq \forall b$
9. $|\forall b| \leq n$
10. Every predicate letter in $\mathscr B$ is in the form $A^n_k(x_1,...,x_p,y_1,...,y_q)$ where $p \leq n$ and $q \leq m$.
11. renaming the sequence $s''$ as $u$.
12. Lets make a interpretation $M'$ where the domain $D$ = $\forall b$
13. Let  $(c_1,...,c_n) \in (A^n_k)^{M'}$ iff  $(c_1,...,c_n) \in (A^n_k)^M$ [gave up]

**Can someone give me a rigorous and complete proof of this theorem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As spaceisdarkgreen said, we'll prove the contrapositive::

> Suppose $\forall x_1,...,x_n\exists y_1,...,y_m\mathscr{B}$ is not valid; then there is a structure $M$ with at most $n$ elements

(We do need "at most" here: the sentence "$\forall x_1,x_2\exists y_1,y_2(y_1\not=y_2)$" is of the above form and not valid but is true in every structure of size $2$.)

**Without loss of generality, we'll work in the purely relational language of $\mathscr{B}$ itself.**

Suppose $N\models\neg \forall x_1,...,x_n\exists y_1,...,y_m\mathscr{B}$. This is the same as saying that there are $a_1,...,a_n\in N$ such that $$N\models \forall y_1,...,y_m\neg\mathscr{B}(a_1,...,a_n, y_1,...,y_m).$$ Now consider the substructure $M$ of $N$ with domain $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$. **This is indeed a substructure since our language is relational** (if we had function or constant symbols involved, we'd be in trouble here). We now use the fact that universal sentences are downwards-absolute:

> If $A, B$ are structures, $A$ is a substructure of $B$, and $B\models\forall z_1,...,z_k\mathscr{U}$ with $\mathscr{U}$ not involving any quantifiers, then $A\models\forall z_1,...,z_k\mathscr{U}$.

Applying this to the **expansions** $\hat{M},\hat{N}$ of $M,N$ respectively gotten by naming the elements $a_1,...,a_n$ by constant symbols $c_1,...,c_n$, we get $$\hat{M}\models \forall y_1,...,y_m\neg\mathscr{B}(c_1,...,c_n,y_1,...,y_m).$$ Passing to the reduct $M$ (and existentially quantifying out the $a_i$s) this gives $M\models\exists x_1,...,x_n\forall y_1,...,y_m\neg\mathscr{B}$ as desired.

Comment: I have only read logic from mendelson , so I dont really know the notion of structure , substructures.

Comment: Hello. I know that it has been almost 2 years since I last talked to you, but I want to apologize. I didn't have the maturity necessary to study effectively from Mendelson, so I have misguided myself for like 9 months before switching to basic FOL proofs. You spent a lot of time on your answers but I was a lost cause at the time, so you time and efforts were wasted on me. I don't remember anything from Logic anymore, but I still accepted your answer since I don't have a reason to believe your answer could be wrong [you are an expert in the field after all].